# Requested values lower than the lower limit of the image

Tags: python, inverse

I am trying to calculate the inverse of a function inside a Gibbs-slice sampler in Python:

```
from pynverse import inversefunc
import numpy as np
import random

def zdens(z):
    return -(z+0.5)**5+3*(z+0.5)**2+z+0.5

myfunc = (lambda z: -(z+0.5)**5+3*(z+0.5)**2+z+0.5)

Nreal,Ngal,currentz=2000,400,0.8
zsamp=np.zeros((Nreal,Ngal))

for m in range(Nreal):
    for k in range(Ngal):
        proposedz=np.random.uniform(0,zdens(currentz))
        zsamp[m][k]=np.random.uniform(inversefunc(myfunc,y_values=proposedz,domain=[0,0.613244]),inversefunc(myfunc, y_values=proposedz,domain=[0.613244,2]))
        zsamp[m][k]=currentz
```

You can find a plot of the function [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUymz.png). The problem comes from the domain argument. The function used should be strictly monotonical, otherwise (as in my case), one should provide the domain in which it is. When I'm not using the domain argument, I don't get any error messages, whereas when I'm using it as shown above I am getting:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-    39-60eac97f0d9a> in <module>
     17     for k in range(Ngal):
     18         proposedz=np.random.uniform(0,zdens(currentz))
---> 19         zsamp[m][k]=np.random.uniform(inversefunc(myfunc,y_values=proposedz,domain=.[0,0.613244]),inversefunc(myfunc, y_values=proposedz,domain=[0.613244,2]))
     20         zsamp[m][k]=currentz

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pynverse/inverse.py in inversefunc(func, y_values,domain, image, open_domain, args, accuracy)
     201         return inv
     202     else:
 --> 203         return inv(y_values)
     204 
     205 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pynverse/inverse.py in inv(yin)
     149                 raise ValueError("Requested values %s lower than the"
     150                                  " lower limit %g of the image" %
 --> 151                                  (yin[mask], ymin))
     152         if ymax is not None:
     153             if (xmax_open and trend == 1) or (xmin_open and trend == -1):

ValueError: Requested values [0.81974978] lower than the lower limit 1.21875 of the image
```

Here is the documentation of the function, which I didn't find helpful in this respect: https://pypi.org/project/pynverse/.

Answer (score 0):

Upon running the above script with a function whose inverse has peaks and could be calculated easily, I found that this error message means that the value I've been trying to calculate the inverse at, is lower than the minimum of the inverse. In other words, I am requesting a value outside the range of the inverse function.